# Why in Java doesn't "!sort.getTestIssue().equals("Y")" get rid of the test stocks from this nasdaqlisted.txt?

Tags: java, string, stringtokenizer

in my advanced java class we are to write an application that reads a .txt file ("nasdaqlisted.txt") that is seperated by pipes ("|") and pull out all of the stocks that have a test issue that = "Y". My application reads my file, but prints out the test cases still.  I'm trying to use an if statement to compare what is stored in testIssue to "Y", but I can't figure out why this won't work.  Here is my source code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class readTextFile
{
    private Scanner input = null;
    private File file = null;

    public void openFile()
    {
        try
        {
            file = new File("nasdaqlisted.txt");
            input = new Scanner(file);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException)
        {
            System.err.println("Error opening file.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public void readFile()
    {
        sortTextFile sort = new sortTextFile();
        try
        {
            try
            {
                file = new File("nasdaqlisted.txt");
                input = new Scanner(file);
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException)
            {
                System.err.println("Error opening file.");
                System.exit(1);
            }


            while (input.hasNext())
            {
                StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(input.nextLine(), "|");
                while (st.hasMoreTokens())
                {
                    input.nextLine();
                    sort.setSymbol(st.nextToken());
                    sort.setSecurity(st.nextToken());
                    sort.setMarket(st.nextToken());
                    sort.setTest(st.nextToken());
                    sort.setFinancial(st.nextToken());
                    sort.setSize(st.nextToken());

                    if (!sort.getTestIssue().equals("Y"))
                    {
                        System.out.println(sort.getSymbol());
                        System.out.println(sort.getSecurityName());
                        System.out.println(sort.getTestIssue());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException noSuchElementException)
        {
            System.err.println("Improperly formed file.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

    }
    public void closeFile()
    {
        if (input != null)
        {
            input.close();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the end of the output I'm getting with the test stocks still printing out:

```
Security Name: Zalicus Inc. - Common Stock
Test Issue: N
Symbol: ZN
Security Name: Zion Oil & Gas Inc - Common Stock
Test Issue: N
Symbol: ZOLT
Security Name: Zoltek Companies, Inc. - Common Stock
Test Issue: N
Symbol: ZU
Security Name: zulily, inc. - Class A Common Stock
Test Issue: N
Symbol: ZVZZT
Security Name: NASDAQ TEST STOCK
Test Issue: Y
Symbol: ZXYZ.A
Security Name: Nasdaq Symbology Test Common Stock
Test Issue: Y
Improperly formed file.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Use your debugger, and inspect the value of sort.getTestIssue(). It probably containsa white space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `System.out.println(sort.getTestIssue());` outputs "Test Issue: Y", then `sort.getTestIssue()` is not equal to "Y".

Maybe you want to use [`endsWith`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith(java.lang.String)) or a regexp or something else

Comment: Aha, it worked!  Now i'm getting a NoSuchElementException error in the middle of my output.